# Jhipster Webpack failure for Jhipster Maven Microservice Gateway application in Dev environment

Tags: maven, microservices, jhipster, api-gateway

I have generated a Sample Microservice application and a Microservice gateway application using Jhipster. Both applications are built using maven and are using Jhipster registry for identification and routing. I am successfully able to build the Micro service application and able to reach it in the assigned localhost port.

I have build issues while building ./mvnw for gateway application. But it builds properly for gradle application and the API's are up. I have issues only for maven in  org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.5.

Its running on Windows 10 machine, latest version of Jhipster.

`Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project api-contact-gateway: Could not exec java: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long`

I have debugged further and could see that the Classpath passed as a part of JVM arguments is too long. But my system variables are properly set.

Comment: Looks like an out of memory issue. See https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8065

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks for the update on the issue. It solves the problem of out of memory issue if i make changes in package.json and set it to max_old_space_size=2048 (Temporary Fix, but by default its is 4096). But still the build fails saying "The filename and extension is too long". But the Microservice application runs for the same root path. Its just a problem with Micoservice Gateway application. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I have updated the question. And the gradle projects builds properly from the same path.

Comment: What makes you think that the classpath is too long ? Do you run mvn or mvnw ?

Comment: Its ./mvnw. As specifies in the documentation

Comment: What is the path of your project folder? Is it too deep? Can you move your project folder to a shorter path? If gradle works, why don't you use it everywhere?

Comment: I have moved it as shortest path as possible in C:\APIGateway.. I would need a maven project instead of gradle. Kindly, let me know the issue with maven project.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea, it seems to be specific to your environment, so I can't reproduce. Maybe you could try different environment like try running from powershell if you ran from cmd.exe. By the way, on Windows it should be `mvnw` not `./mnvw` but that's probably what you typed.

Comment: I did try using power shell but still the issue persists.

Comment: Sorry I don’t have other suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I coudn't find any specific solution. I just lowered my Jhipster version to 4.14